# How to debug a WebMethod in JDeveloper?

Tags: java, web-services, debugging, jdeveloper, webmethod

I'm using JDeveloper 11.1.2.4.0 and I'm trying to debug one of the web services. I have a java file and inside that a webmethod. I am setting breakpoints but when I click debug all I can do is pause or unpause. Step over is not available. I went through multiple websites to find out how to do it properly but just can't do it.

Answer (score 0):

web method can be tested using HttpAnalyzer. I think it is right-click on navigaiton panel and option "test webservice"